# Vertical UIScrollView in a Vertical UIScrollView in XCODE IB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

All, 
I have a vertical scrolling view on an VC in Xcode Interface builder. I am putting another UIScrollView in it , which again is vertical scrolling.

[image]

So I have a container view in my UIScrollView and that goes to an external VC with a ScrollView and then a UILabel.

The UILabel does not scroll and I have set all the constraints - so they are all correct and blue.

Can anyone advise ?

Comment: The UIScrollView will not scroll unless it's contentSize exceeds the bounds of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a UIScrollView to scroll, it needs to have a reason to. If you put a label in a UIScrollView and that label can be seen entirely without having to scroll, the UIScrollView will not have scrolling enabled (since there would be no reason to, logically).

All you have to do is ensure that whatever the content is of the scrollView is larger than the original frame of the scrollView.

[image]

The scrollView ends where the top arrow is pointing, but I have stretched the textView beyond the end of the scrollView (bottom arrow).

And again with the scrollView within the scrollView:

[image]

They both scroll correctly this way, wihtout adding any code, or constraints.